# ¿Cómo guardar estado de botón en localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

tengo un botón que para todo el sonido de mi página y otro que vuelve a reproducir el sonido:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       /*** Mute all ***/
       $('#mute_all').on('click',function(){

          /*** Mute all video and audio on page ***/
          $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
             /*** Do it here globally ***/
             $(this).prop('muted', true);
          });

       });

       /*** UnMute all ***/
       $('#unmute_all').on('click',function(){

          /*** Un Mute all video and audio on page ***/
          $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
             /*** Do it here globally ***/
             $(this).prop('muted', false);
          });

       });


    });
```

El problema es que cuando refresco la página o voy a otra parte de la misma no me guarda los cambios. ¿cómo podría hacerlo con un localstorage?

Muchísimas gracias por anticipado!

Comment: Carlos, ya actualicé mi respuesta, espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que el estado de botón lo vas a guardar en un storage llamado **muted**, pues sería:

**Cuando el documento esté listo ejecutas esto:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var muted;
    if (localStorage.muted == undefined) { //Comprobamos si el usuario es nuevo o no       
        muted = "false"; //El estado por defecto de muted
        localStorage.muted = muted;
    } else {
        muted = localStorage.muted;

        if (muted == "false") {
            //No está muteado
        } else {
            //Si está muteado
        }
    }
});
```

> Recuerda que si el usuario **borra los datos de navegación ¡el
>   **localStorage.muted** se perderá!

El valor de **localStorage.muted** lo deberás cambiar en tus eventos click de los botones `#muteall` y `#unmuteall`:

> **NOTA**: te voy a hacer una función con un pequeño truco para que puedas cambiar los estados de **muted con un solo botón**, y aquí va el
>   ejemplo entero adaptado un poco a tu código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* 
        0 => no está muteado
        1 => si está muteado
    */
    var muted;

    // Definimos las funciones de mute() y unmute()
    function mute() {
        $('body video, body audio').each(function(){ 
            $(this).prop('muted', true); });
        });
        localStorage.muted = 1;
        $("#muted").html("Unmute all"); //Cambiamos el texto del botón
    }

    function unmute() {
        $('body video, body audio').each(function(){ 
            $(this).prop('muted', false); });
        });
        localStorage.muted = 0;
        $("#muted").html("Mute all"); //Cambiamos el texto del botón
    }

        if (localStorage.muted == undefined) { //Comprobamos si el usuario es nuevo o no       
            muted = 0; //El estado por defecto de muted
            localStorage.muted = muted;
        } else {
            muted = localStorage.muted;

            if (muted == 0) {
                unmute();
            } else {
                mute();
            }
        }

    $("#muted").click(function() {

        if (muted === 1) {
            unmute();
        } else {
            mute();
        }

        muted = 1 - muted;
       /* Aquí está el truco:
           Cuando muted valga 1 => 1-1=0
           Cuando muted valga 0 => 1-0=1
           Y así sucesivamente
       */      

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<button id="muted">Mute all</button>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con el siguiente codigo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Verificas es estado al cargar la pagina
   if(localStorage.getItem('muted')){
     $('#mute_all').click()
   } else {
     $('#unmute_all').click()
   }

   /*** Mute all ***/
   $('#mute_all').on('click',function(){

      /*** Mute all video and audio on page ***/
      $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
         /*** Do it here globally ***/
         $(this).prop('muted', true);
         // Guardas el estado
         localStorage.setItem('muted',true)
      });

   });

   /*** UnMute all ***/
   $('#unmute_all').on('click',function(){

      /*** Un Mute all video and audio on page ***/
      $('body video, body audio').each(function(){
         /*** Do it here globally ***/
         $(this).prop('muted', false);
         // Guardas el estado
         localStorage.setItem('muted',false)
      });

   });


});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas. Desgraciadamente no me funciona ninguna de las dos soluciones!! :/